# Segmentation fault while adding a new node to a list

Tags: c, list

i have a problem while searching a list and trying to add a new node.
The Code looks as follows

```
struct sizelist{
    int currentsize, origsize;
    struct sizelist * next;
};
typedef struct sizelist item;
```

Here are sizes the content, items is the amount of nodes connected and next is the next node.

```
void firstfit(item tosort){
  int junksize = tosort.currentsize;
  int paired;
  item* current;
  for(int i=0;i<containeramount;i++){
    if(containers[i].currentsize - junksize >=0){
      paired = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  current = &containers[paired];
  while(current->next!=NULL){
    current = current->next;
  }
  containers[paired].currentsize = containers[paired].currentsize - junksize;
  current->next = &tosort;
 }
```

`containers` is an array of `item`.

This seems to work now. But now i have a problem with my output:

```
void writeout(){
  item* current;
  for(int i=0;i<containeramount;i++){
    current = &containers[i];
    for(int j=0;; j++){
      printf("%d ",current->currentsize);
      if(current->next!=NULL){
        current = current->next;
      }
      else{
        break;
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Now you also have all to understand the program.
I give it for example 3 containers of size 10 each and things to sort of size 6,8,1,5. It looks like `firstfit` makes it's job, but the `writeout` method not.
The proper output here should be:

10 6 1

10 8

10 5

Here the output for origsize is:

10 3

10 3

10 3

and for currentsize it is:

3 134515941

2 134515941

5 134515941

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Do you have stable way to reproduce the problem? What is the initial values to do it? Have you tried to use debugger?

Comment: Please Format your code for better readability.

Comment: `paired` might be uninitialised if none of the containers fit. Initialise it with an illegal index, say `-1` and enforce that it has a legal index later.

Comment: When you say `current = containers[paires]`, you copy the contents. If you have a linked list, you want pointers to existing items, not copies. Likewise, the line `current = *current.next` look wrong. It should be `current = current->next` and `current` should be a pointer to an `item`.

Comment: Finally, here: `current.next = &tosort` you take the address of a local variable, which goes out of scope the next instant. That means that the pointer you store will be invalid. (Not that it matters, because `current` goes out of scope, too.)

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea to keep a count of the number of nodes connected in the node? AFAICT, it means if you insert a node at the end, you have to walk back and increment *every nodecount* in the list, which is probably bug-prone and inefficient.

Comment: If you never look at the "stuff" in a container then why put it in the container at all? Your function seems to have no rhyme or reason to it. Why is `paired` set the way it is? What happens if it is never set? Why do `containers[paired].currentsize = containers[paired].currentsize - junksize;`, _reducing_ `currentsize` (if `junksize` is positive!) when you are _adding_ an item to the container?

Comment: EOF there is no problem with that. An item can be a container and stuff i put in a container, and i only keep track of how many things i put into the container and ignore the stuff in it.

Comment: The whole programm is little bit longer, I need to make a sorting machine, which i give the size of containers and the size of things i have to sort. I wanted to make it as a list where the beginning is the container and every node after is the stuff inside. After it is done it will write all of this out.

Comment: @Shuumi, The only place the `next` field is assigned is at the end, but `tosort` is on the stack, so a temporary address is being kept.  Also, the second `for` loop implies values for `next` have already been assigned (not shown), but conventionally, linked lists end with a null pointer.  In that loop, `next` is never checked and could be null, dereferenced the next time through the loop.

Comment: It looks like @M Oehm 's answer gives the true point of the problem. It seems to work, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the latest revision of the code is much improved,
but `tosort` is passed into `firstfit(item tosort)` by value.
That means within the function `firstfit(item tosort)`, `tosort` is a temporary
variable that is destroyed at the end of the function.
(This was in the earlier version of the program too, but we looked
at other problems first.)

Now that the function is doing its work on the actual contents
of `containers[paired]` rather than on a temporary copy of something,
the final `next` pointer in the list is being set (as desired),
but it points to the temporary object `tosort`.
When the function ends, `tosort` goes out of scope.
Presumably, something else gets written to the same block of virtual
memory by the time you try to print this out.

This will work better if the function is changed to
`firstfit(item* tosort)`, that is, pass a pointer instead of a copy of
the struct.
This will behave a little bit more like you would expect a call to a function
to behave in Java.

---

**Note:** The remarks below refer to [revision 2 of the question.](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31746317/2) 
The code in the question has since been modified so that it follows
these recommendations.

---

I'm finding so many apparent errors in the code it's hard to keep track
of all of them, but I suspect that the segmentation fault is here:

```
    current = containers[paired];
    for(int i=0;i<containers[paired].items;i++){
        current = *current.next;
    }
```

One of the errors in the code is that you declare `item current;`.
That means `current` is always a temporary data structure and is *never*
actually "in" `containers[paired]`. When you do `current.next = &tosort;` the only thing that is changed is a field of this temporary data structure, which goes out of scope on the next line and is destroyed. So in effect that line does nothing at all. It most decidedly does *not* insert any data in `containers[paired]`.

On the other hand, `containers[paired].items++;` *does* increment the counter in  `containers[paired]`. So now `containers[paired].items` is greater than the number of items actually in the linked list. This means that when you come into this function some other time and execute the loop above with the same `containers[paired]`, you will execute `current = *current.next;` too many times; you end up trying to access the `next` node of the last node in the list, and then you segfault.

The standard way to implement a simple linked list in C is to set
the `next` pointer to 0 (or `NULL` if it's defined as 0) whenever
there is no actual "next" thing in the list; the last thing in the list
*always* has `next` equal to 0. In order to find the last thing in the list,
you don't *count* the number of times to follow the `next` pointer;
you simply follow the `next` pointer until you reach the node whose
`next` pointer is 0, and then you stop.

I highly recommend getting rid of `items`. You can always find out how many items are in the container by following the list to the end and counting the number of nodes you encounter. Sure, this takes longer than just reading the value of `items`, but it will give you *the correct answer* and it *will not cause a segmentation fault*. Get your program to work without error, and then you can think about making it faster if you need to (for example by putting `items` back in your struct and making it actually have the correct value).

Comment: Thank you, I can programm in java, but i don't understand that POINTER style. I have edited my first post now because i have another problem, that i do not understand anymore.